# Is it possible to set/recognize if a contour is enclosing a peak or a hole in OpenCV?

Tags: image-processing, opencv

I am trying to recognize a special cell type on an image. What I' am looking for are some color-peaks (image 1, peaks are marked with blue dots) in specified distance. My approach is, layer-wise tresholding the image and counting contours. Here is the pseudo-code:

```
FOR Treshold= 250 to 0 STEP=5 
  treshold image
  count contours having specified area
  IF specified number of contours found BREAK
```

Unfortunatelly, there are some cells, having holes instead of peaks. These holes also produce contours (image 2).

My questions are 
1: is it possible, to call cvFindContours so, that it discards "hole"-contours?

2: If not, is it possible to determing from the CvContour structure wether it is enclosing a peak or a hole?

I was not able to find it out myself reading OpenCV code.

Thank you!

[image: Cell containing peaks]

[image: Cell containing holes]

Comment: Can you include the actual images ?

Comment: These actually are the actual images (without blue dots marking points of interest). Or do you mean images of the contours? I think the problem is general, not special to cells.

Comment: Do you mean these are the actual images as in the actual resolution ? It would be at least nice to include the input images (without any modifications). The problem is general, and might be a simple one to solve: find the mean intensity inside the closed contour, then you can determine whether that is a peak or a valley. There might be other ways to approach it, but there is nothing I can with your included input.